# django custom validators function?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-validation

I have a model named X which has a

STATUS_CHOICES = (
(STATUS_A, 'A'),
(STATUS_B, 'B'),
(STATUS_O, 'Other'),
)
and the field name status = models.CharField(max_length=48, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

here i am trying to write a custom validator to for a spreadsheet when uploaded to check for the value that should return only the STATUS_CHOICES and any other value it should return error how should i write ?

**validators.py**

```
from app.model import X
def validate_A_or_B(value):
    return value in dict(X.STATUS_CHOICES).values()
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom validation for a field like this:

validators.py:

```
from your_view.models import X
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

 def validate_status(value):

     if value not in dict(X.STATUS_CHOICES).values():
         raise ValidationError("your message")
     return value
```

You can use it in your models field like this: `models.CharField(max_length=48, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, validators = [validate_status])` don't forget to include `from .validators import validate_status`

Comment: i mean the code phrase dict(X.status_Choices).values() is it correct?

Comment: Yes i created a custom validator implying that

Comment: If this helped you can mark as accepted.